# How to attach selection model in BufferedStore Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am trying to attach checkbox model in extjs grid. I am using Buffered Store but it is not happening. I declear `var checkBoxSelMod = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();` then in grid configuration using `selModel :checkBoxSelMod,` but I don't understand why it is throwing. [My working Fiddler](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jd0)

Comment: why you need a selectionModel?

Comment: @Mr.George I want to select cells

Comment: ok understood, so you want a checkbox column?

Comment: Yes, Check Fiddler

Comment: why you don't use a checkcolumn?

Comment: Did'nt get you can you please change in fiddler and show me.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jd2 like this?

Comment: ya, but selection is not happening. Can you please make that and post answer then I will accept. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.George Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
{
            xtype:'checkcolumn',
            dataIndex:'selection',
            listeners:{
                checkchange:function(checkbox , rowIndex , checked , record , eOpts){
                    if(checked){
                        var selections=grid.getSelection();
                        selections.push(record);
                        grid.setSelection(selections);
                    }else{
                        var selectionsDelete=grid.getSelection();
                        Ext.Array.removeAt(selectionsDelete,selectionsDelete.indexOf(record))
                        grid.setSelection(selectionsDelete);
                    }                             
                }
            }
        }
```

Remember to ad multi selection on grid:

```
selModel: {mode: 'MULTI'}
```

Here is a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jd2

Use grid.getSelection() to get records selected.